# Whats the best way to setup multiple PHP versions + NGINX on macOS?

Tags: php, macos, nginx

I'm really struggling with multiple PHP versions on macOS (my local workstation).

Currently, I have a website written in PHP 5.6 that is hosted in NGINX. In the past days, I was using LAMPP (php 5.6) to start apache and PHP. But I had some issues because NGINX isn't exactly the same as Apache.

So I wanted to have a more realistic workstation... Today I installed the NGINX and PHP 5.6 (and php-fpm) on my mac, but I didn't work properly then I uninstalled everything and I'm trying again.

Anywaaaaays: whats the best way to set up my local machine and have both PHP 5.6, PHP 7.2 and NGINX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at docker, seriously it so easy and you can run containers with different versions

https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Comment: Docker also works well using memcached? I already hear about docker but never give a try. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I have a php7 one with some stuff configured like composer .. i think ubuntu is a better image instead of centos ... https://github.com/ricardosaracino/docker-symphony/blob/master/Dockerfile.apache

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, try using MAMP (https://www.mamp.info)

They have option to use NGINX server. see attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xojxB.png)

Comment: Hmm seems to be the easiest/fast way. Thanks :)